# How to put all items of a list of type decimal together into a single decimal variable

Tags: c#, list

I have a list of type decimal, every decimal item of the list contains one digit (I dont care about memory). How can I loop through this list and put all of its items into one decimal?

```
List<decimal> individualnumberslist = new List<decimal>();

foreach (decimal digit in individualnumberslist) 
{ 
    decimal resultnumber = /here/     
}
```

Comment: Could you give an example input/output?

Answer (score 3):

```
List<decimal> individualnumberslist = new List<decimal>();
decimal resultnumber = 0;

foreach (decimal digit in individualnumberslist) 
{ 
    resultnumber = resultnumber*10 + digit;
}
```

Comment: You cannot re-declare resultnumber within the loop

Answer (score 1):

You can put the digits in a string and parse it:

```
Decimal resultNumber =
  Decimal.Parse(String.Concat(individualnumberslist.Select(Convert.ToString)));
```

[Edited, only to make it edited...]

Comment: Looks like a pretty bad idea to me: serializing and parsing is costly, and it will do the same work as the classical algorithm behind the scènes, with the added type conversion.

Comment: @Falanwe: I posted it as an alternative. Storing digits in a `List<Decimal>` is a pretty bad idea to start with, and the OP specificially said that memory cost was not an issue, so performance shouldn't be either.

Comment: You're right, it shouldn't be an issue, and 1-digit decimals are really strange. Maybe we could send the list to a web-service that make the calculation for us? It would be fun!

Comment: Why the downvote? If you don't explain what you think is wrong, it can't improve the answer.

Answer (score 0):

"Putting all items of a list together" makes me instantly think of linq's [Aggregate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548651.aspx) method

```
List<decimal> individualnumberslist = new List<decimal>();

return individualnumberslist.Aggregate((accumulator, digit) => accumulator * 10 + digit);
```